# Magento 2 Component manager (extension installation)

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, composer

I'm developing an extension for Magento 2, and was wondering what are my options for the installation process for users.
I saw in the magento documentation that there supposed to be a component manager where you are supposed to be able to install extensions with.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/compman-start.html

When I try to acces this from the Admin I am routed to page that wants to start the Magento installation process from the start (Magento 2 is obviously already installed).

Is this not yet in the Beta version of Magento 2?
What are my other options?
Am I supposed to upload my extension to a composer repository?

Answer (score 3):

The functionality described in the document was released after Magento 2 Merchant Beta release.

If you try to install from the development branch on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2), you should see the Component Management UI. However, it won't be possible to use all its features before Magento sources will be published to the Composer repository. That will happen during GA release.